# Lightbox2 not initiating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox2

Ok so what I thought would take me few minutes to implement has now taken up over an hour of my time and I'm just completely puzzled.

I downloaded [lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), followed the instructions; embedding their CSS and JS in the head of my index.html

```
<link href="lightbox/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lightbox/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

I am only testing it on localhost if that makes any difference. The paths are set correctly 100% and so are the paths to the 4 images the CSS requires..

Now in my body I am using the a href with the `data-lightbox` attribute like this

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="gallery/i1.jpg" data-lightbox="group" data-title="Optional caption.">
    <img class="example-image" src="gallery/i1.jpg" alt="desc">
</a>
<a class="example-image-link" href="gallery/i2.jpg" data-lightbox="group" data-title="Optional caption.">
    <img class="example-image" src="gallery/i2.jpg" alt="desc">
</a>
```

There is nothing else on the page so the result looks like this:
[image: result]

**The issue is that when I click one of the images, instead of the lightbox popping up the image just opens in a fullscreen tab.** It's like the lightbox is not working at all, and it just follows the `a href` to the image.. I even tried JSFiddle and loaded the same CSS and JS as external resources and it's doing the exact same thing. See for yourselves -> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wb99bhru/)

I am open to any ideas.. Really don't understand what am I missing.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me **Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/OyxyrP Could be the way your loading your scripts?

Comment: and with the same sources as I did, correct? How's that possible?

Comment: Yep using the same ones that you used in jsfiddle @1cgonza is on to something

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should move the `<script src="lightbox/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>` bit to the end of your `body` tag in the HTML, instead of the `head`. The problem is that if the script is in the head, it will run before the images are ready to be parsed by the library.

Comment: I just figured that out myself... I swear I read the instructions 5 times and only the 6th time I notice it says "Include the Javascript at the bottom of your page before the closing </body> tag" Really sorry about this post..

Comment: Perfect solution. It's the only one I've found that has worked.